# dotnet test > is there a way to show list of tests ran in console?

Tags: xunit.net, dotnet-cli

When running `dotnet test`, is there a way of showing a list of all tests ran in console instead of some output file?

Would be ideal to see a list like this in console:

```
x test1
 test2
 test3
x test4
```

instead of just overall test statistics (ran, failed, skipped).

Answer (score 56):

I'm using .Net 6 with NUnit on macOS. Setting the verbosity level for `dotnet test` does not print a list of all executed tests (successful or otherwise).

What **does** print such a list is setting the logger verbosity like this:

```
dotnet test -l "console;verbosity=normal"
```

Comment: Verbosity option works in .NET SDK 5 and older, `dotnet test -v:normal`. As of .NET SDK 6 you have to use logger option as per @Raginmari's answer, `dotnet test -l:"console;verbosity=normal"`.

Comment: `dotnet test -v quiet --nologo -l:"console;verbosity=normal"  `   --  only test output

Comment: Is there any documentation on these parameters?

Answer (score 38):

Found it. settig verbosity level lists tests:

`dotnet test -v=normal` (or higher)

Comment: In addition to this, it might be useful to launch `dotnet build` before, and then add the `--no-build` flag to `dotnet test`. In this way, the tests output is a bit more readable, because it doesn't include the build logs

Comment: The `-v` flag "Set the MSBuild verbosity level. Allowed values are q[uiet], m[inimal], n[ormal], d[etailed], and diag[nostic]" . Seems not related to the test itself.

Comment: This does not seem to be working for me.

Comment: Verbosity option works in .NET SDK 5 and older, `dotnet test -v:normal`. As of .NET SDK 6 you have to use logger option as per @Raginmari's answer, `dotnet test -l:"console;verbosity=normal"`.

Answer (score 0):

`-v=normal` won't work with dotnet. it's for msbuild.
in dotnet you need to use `-v:normal` or just `-v:n`
but it won't solve your problem
you can also use `-t` argument to output all test names
I didin't find correct argument